# How to map object using reduce method?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have tried to make the class Person with its own **map** method that I called **mapper**. The requirement is using reduce method and send a callback to mapper.

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, age, job) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
    this.job = job
  }
  mapper(cb) {
    return Object.entries(this).reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc = cb(item)
      return acc
    }, {})
  }
}
```

I make instance of this class.

```
const kate = new Person('Kate', 34, 'dev')
const result = kate.mapper(([key, val]) => (val === 34 ? { [key]: val } : {}))
console.log(result)
// {}
```

I should get my result as

```
// {age: 34}
```

The problem is because the acc is equal to the last condition (when comparing to job).
It seems like the acc is overwritten constantly during iteration.
I have tried to solve that problem using forEach look in mapper method, but I got some errors. The callback should looks the same like now. I know that I should change sth in mapper, but I don't have any idea what. I tried use Object.assing() either.

Comment: *"The requirement is using reduce method..."* Whose requirement is that? `reduce` is rarely the right tool to reach for (outside functional programming with predefined, tested reducer functions). Otherwise, `reduce` is overcomplicated and hard to read.

Comment: What's wrong with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? Why are you just re-inventing the wheel in an overly obtuse way?

Comment: Your `.reduce()` callback always returns the return value of `cb(item)`. So the final result of `.mapper()` is the return value of the last `cb(item)` call which will be an empty array - unless the `age` property somehow gets to be the last element in the array and has a value of `34`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just got the exercise from my teacher. Probably, the reason is to study a harder way of solving this problem. If I can use only map, I won't write this post...

Comment: I figured it was something like that. :-) Sounds like your teacher has been infected with the "it's an array thing, I guess I should use `reduce`" bug. FWIW: https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544, https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224 Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems like the acc is overwritten constantly during iteration.

That's correct, because you get a new object from `cb`, and then you return that object.

If you want to combine the objects returned by `cb`, you could change it to use `Object.assign` to copy the properties of the object returned by `cb` onto `acc`:

```
mapper(cb) {
  return Object.entries(this).reduce((acc, item) => {
    Object.assign(acc, cb(item)); // ***
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

...but really, `reduce` just isn't the tool to use here; the accumulator never changes (we just modify it). Still, you said that was the requirement...

You can also combine

```
    Object.assign(acc, cb(item)); // ***
    return acc;
```

into

```
    return Object.assign(acc, cb(item)); // ***
```

since `Object.assign` returns its first argument (`acc`, in the above).

Comment: Many thanks! It works. As I mentioned, I have tried to do using Object.assign(), but I see that I have made it more complicated than you.